# Date Criteria in Pass through SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been provided the following information to place into an access pass through query to pull data from works SQL:

```
exec dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N', '2017-01-16', '2017-01-23', -1
```

To avoid manually having to edit the dates on a weekly basis, I am hoping to either find a way for including GETDATE() - 7 days or somehow edit the dates in the query via a table or form in my access database. I don't have much experience with SQL, very limited and my skill in access is all picked up from google or Youtube videos, so I apologize in advance if my question seems silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access VBA (or any language that can make COM interface -e.g., PHP, Python, R), you can dynamically change the SQL in stored queries using its [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) collection:

```vb
Public Sub UpdatePassThruQ   
    Dim strSQL As String    

    strSQL =  "dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N'," _
                   & " '" & Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Date), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "'," _
                   & " '" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "', -1"

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PassThroughQuery").SQL = strSQL        ' UPDATE SQL
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PassThroughQuery").Execute             ' EXECUTE       
End Sub
```

SQL String Output *(for today)*

```vb
Debug.Print "exec dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N'," _
                 & " '" & Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Date), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "'," _
                 & " '" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "', -1"

' exec dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N', '2017-01-17', '2017-01-24', -1
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Parfait. I am getting Run-time error 3065, cannot execute a select query?

Comment: Try removing *exec* at beginning of SQL statement.

Comment: Hi Parfait, this resulted in Run-time error 3265, Item not found in this collection. Thanks

Comment: What line resulted in that error? Did you remove *exec* in strSQL? The reason being is it becomes redundant having that and `.Execute` together.

Comment: debug is referencing CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PassThroughQuery").SQL = strSQL        ' UPDATE SQL

Comment: Apologies, I have now removed the exec from the SQL statement (didn't save properly) and am now getting Compile Error: Syntax error with debug referencing Public Sub UpdatePassThruQ() Am I meant to be referencing something between the brackets :/ ?

Comment: It is assumed that you have created a pass-though query called PassThoughQuery. If you PT query is called "zoo", then using QueryDefs("zoo"). so you have to create a WORKING pt query first. That PT query can be anything - but once created you will modify it over and over on the "fly" as per the example code.  So put in your original hard coded query and get the PT query to work by clicking on it. Once that works then you can try with code. ALSO you need to set return records = true or false depending on what the SP does.

Comment: I finally got it to work                                                                                                     Public Sub UpdatePassThruQ()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N'," _
                   & " '" & Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Date), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "'," _
                   & " '" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "', -1"

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Service Orders").SQL = strSQL        ' UPDATE SQL
End Sub - The output being dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N', '2017-01-23', '2017-01-30', -1 in my PT SQL. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Great! So you don't execute in VBA? If solution helped please accept (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.

Comment: Hi Parfait, Apparently not. Extremely thrilled with the result and now using it for several PT query's. Out of curiosity, do you have to include the entire PT query script or can you have the string update by locating only portion of the script?

Comment: Simply flip the equality. Assign a VBA string to PT's sql and then use `Replace` or any other string operation on the variable. When done re-assign it back like above here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use GetDate()

```
exec dbr_b2b_so_status_report 'N', CAST(GetDate() - 7 AS Date), CAST(GetDate() AS Date), -1
```